# using labels results in huge amount of warnings

Tags: compiling, labels

In my document I use a number of references to Lemmas/Theorems and the like which all work as intended. This includes some custom commands. However, I get anywhere from 1 to 5 LaTeX-Warnings each time I reference one of the labels in my document.
Also, the compilation of the MWE takes about 4 seconds, which is more than I would expect, given the small size (that's not what this question is about, but I thought it might be useful).
Those 13 warnings aren't too bad, but in my main document, I currently have 90 such label-related warnings which makes it really hard to find other warnings.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

% custom labels
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mylabel[2][]{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\label{#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\crefdetail}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref*{#2}}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{remark} \label{label}
        Label
    \end{remark}
    
    \begin{remark} \mylabel[myLabel]{mylabel}
        myLabel
    \end{remark}
    
    \begin{remark} \label{label_detail_main}$ $
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item \label{label_detail_sub1} Text
            \item \label{label_detail_sub2} Text
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remark}
    
    Here I reference \cref{label},  % line 34
    \nameref{mylabel},              % line 35
    $\crefdetail{label_detail_main}{label_detail_sub1}$ and   % line 36
    $\crefdetail{label_detail_main}{label_detail_sub2}$.      % line 37

\end{document}
```

resulting in this document

[image]

and these warnings

```
labels_log.tex 34 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.

labels_log.tex 35 LaTeX Warning: Reference `mylabel' on page 1 undefined on input line 35.

labels_log.tex 36 LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.

labels_log.tex 36 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.

labels_log.tex 36 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.

labels_log.tex 36 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_sub1' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.

labels_log.tex 37 LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.

labels_log.tex 37 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.

labels_log.tex 37 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.

labels_log.tex 37 LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_sub2' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.

labels_log.tex  LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

labels_log.tex  LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

labels_log.tex  Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `labels_log.out' has changed. Rerun to get outlines right or use package `bookmark'.
```

I also get this console output, if that helps

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
(H:/Studium/BA/MWEs/labels_log.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.
sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty)
 (C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-langpatches.def)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilechec
k.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounte
r.sty)))
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/cleveref\cleveref.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.d
ef)
No file labels_log.aux.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestr
ing.sty)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `mylabel' on page 1 undefined on input line 35.

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input
 line 36.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 
36.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 
36.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_sub1' on page 1 undefined on input line 
36.

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input
 line 37.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 
37.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_main' on page 1 undefined on input line 
37.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `label_detail_sub2' on page 1 undefined on input line 
37.

[1{C:/Users/Leo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(labels_log.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `labels_log.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on labels_log.pdf (1 page, 37672 bytes).
SyncTeX written on labels_log.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on labels_log.log.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
(H:/Studium/BA/MWEs/labels_log.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.
sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty)
 (C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-langpatches.def)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilechec
k.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounte
r.sty)))
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/cleveref\cleveref.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.d
ef) (labels_log.aux)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty)
(C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestr
ing.sty)) (labels_log.out) (labels_log.out)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd) [1{C:/Users/Leo/AppDat
a/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (labels_log.aux) )<C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on labels_log.pdf (1 page, 49761 bytes).
SyncTeX written on labels_log.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on labels_log.log.
```

Comment: Did you run more than once? Once I compiled a few times (I use `latexmk` so that happens automatically) there are no warnings from that MWE.

Comment: Yes, just did. Nothing changed

Comment: Then update your miktex both in miktex-user mode and in miktex-admin mode (look at the log, you have both stuff under `Program Files` and under `Roaming` so you need to update both. I also have `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01>` on my side.

Comment: I did update both before submitting the report, so can't be that. I might try a new installation alter today and see if that helps as this seems to be on my side.

Comment: MikTeX does not normally need to be reinstalled (and because of the stuff you have in `Roaming` problems still remain. You need to update in both modes using the miktex console. (note that it does not really have anything to do with admin mode on your windows).

Comment: In which editor are you compiling? If it is texworks check if it has a --clean setting in the profile and delete it.

Comment: @daleif yes, I went into user and admin mode in the miktex console and installed all available updates

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using TexWorks with pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex. removing --clean didn't work. I will try around using different settings there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed to dpfLaTeX. That removed the warnings and it now also runs significantly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the processing tool `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`.
Changing that to only `pdfLaTeX` solved both problems (unnecessary warnings and the long compile time).